# How to set a grid for kernelbb() in adehabitatHR packge

Tags: r, kernel-density, adehabitathr

I'm trying to calculate home range size of individuals. So, I'm studying several functions in `adehabitatHR` package, including `MCP()`, `KernelUD()`, `kernellbb()` and `BRB()`.

I'd like to use same grid of background for those analyses.
so I made a grid like this, after read this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41683905/grid-too-small-for-kernelud-getverticeshr-adehabitathr-home-range-estimation) and this [link](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_pass_a_grid_into_kernelUD_package_adehabitatHR_in_R).

```
> str(GU2)
'data.frame':   2669 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ month     : int  2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ Collecting: POSIXct, format: "2023-02-04 00:01:00" ...
 $ Longitude : num  108181 108170 108050 108007 107973 ...
 $ Latitude  : num  510220 510186 510133 510114 510075 ..

# Setting CRS 
> coordinates(GU2) <- c("Longitude", "Latitude")
> proj4string(GU2) <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs") #+init=epsg:4326
> GU2 <- spTransform(GU2, CRS("+proj=tmerc +lat_0=38 +lon_0=127 +k=1 +x_0=200000 +y_0=600000 
                           +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs"))
# Grid
> x <- seq(min(GU2$Longitude), max(GU2$Longitude), by=50) 
> y <- seq(min(GU2$Latitude), max(GU2$Latitude), by=50)
> xy <- expand.grid(x=x,y=y)
> coordinates(xy) <- ~x+y
> gridded(xy) <- TRUE
> proj4string(xy) <- CRS("+proj=tmerc +lat_0=38 +lon_0=127 +k=1 +x_0=200000 +y_0=600000 
                           +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs") 

# BBMM analysis
> GU2_traj <- as.ltraj(xy = GU2[,c("Latitude", "Longitude")],
                 date = GU2$Collecting, 
                 id = GU2$month)
> GU2_bbmm.2 <- kernelbb(GU2_traj[1], sig1 =0.42, sig2 = 109.06, grid = xy)
```

However, there is no data in 'GU2_bbmm.2' (Please, look at the 'GU2_bbmm.2@data$ud')

```
> str(GU2_bbmm.2)
Formal class 'estUD' [package "adehabitatHR"] with 9 slots
  ..@ h          :List of 2
  .. ..$ values: Named num [1:2] 1.76e-01 1.19e+04
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "sig12" "sig22"
  .. ..$ meth  : chr "BB-specified"
  ..@ vol        : logi FALSE
  ..@ data       :'data.frame': 837 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ ud: num [1:837] NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ...
  ..@ coords.nrs : num(0) 
  ..@ grid       :Formal class 'GridTopology' [package "sp"] with 3 slots
  .. .. ..@ cellcentre.offset: Named num [1:2] 107863 509840
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "Var2" "Var1"
  .. .. ..@ cellsize         : Named num [1:2] 50 50
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "Var2" "Var1"
  .. .. ..@ cells.dim        : Named int [1:2] 31 27
  .. .. .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "Var2" "Var1"
  ..@ grid.index : int [1:837] 1 32 63 94 125 156 187 218 249 280 ...
  ..@ coords     : num [1:837, 1:2] 107863 107863 107863 107863 107863 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : NULL
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "Var2" "Var1"
  ..@ bbox       : num [1:2, 1:2] 107838 509815 109388 511165
  .. ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "Var2" "Var1"
  .. .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "min" "max"
  ..@ proj4string:Formal class 'CRS' [package "sp"] with 1 slot
  .. .. ..@ projargs: chr "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=38 +lon_0=127 +k=1 +x_0=200000 +y_0=600000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs"
  .. .. ..$ comment: chr "PROJCRS[\"unknown\",\n    BASEGEOGCRS[\"unknown\",\n        DATUM[\"Unknown based on GRS80 ellipsoid\",\n      "| __truncated__
```

Using the same grid, `BRB()` function also made only NaNs. But `kernelUD()` works well.

When I put 50 in the grid argument of `kernellbb()` and `BRB()` function, they works. So I think my grid is something wrong. How can I make an appropriate grid for the functions in adehabitatHR package?

Comment: It's  possible that different functions handle grid making or grid input differently. When I looked at `sp:coordinates` fn help page, it became fairly clear that it expected an n x m array or similar data structure. Other functions may accept a specification of `~x+y`. Realize that multiple packages  have `coordinate` functions. Both pkg:raster and pkg:sp have a function by that name and there may be other. It's sometimes that case that pkgs will copy from another package. You need to check. Is there is a utility function delivering all the packages with a given function name? I don't know.

Comment: @IRTFM To make a grid, I copy the code from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41683905/grid-too-small-for-kernelud-getverticeshr-adehabitathr-home-range-estimation). I could not find the reason of this problem. I also checked calling pkg did not make any change.

Comment: Deleted my first comment bc it was not correct. Appears from the help page for `kernelbb` that it uses parameters to build a grid rather than having a grid delivered to it. Suggest you review the parameter's description and then review the Examples section.